# How can I change color of my e-book?

Tags: pdf, editing

How can I change the font or background color of my PDF e-book. I use Adobe reader v10 and it has no default option to change this.

Is there a way to edit the e-book to change the font or background color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from [here](http://lifehacker.com/5483656/change-the-background-color-in-adobe-reader-for-eye+friendly-contrast):

1. Open Adobe Reader. Go to Edit - Preferences - Accessibility.
2. Make sure the "Replace Document Colors" is checked and click on Custom Color.
3. Click "Page Background" color and then select "other color."

I don't know if the version of Adobe Reader matters or not (or if it matches what you have).

You could also consider using a different PDF view. I personally perfer [SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html). It has a settings.txt file that you can edit to customize the text, background etc., which can be accessed via `Settings` > `Advanced Options` (options your default text editor for txt files).

***NOTE: I am using SumatraPDF v2.4***

Comment: I think version matters because there is not Accesibility under Preferences in not available in my version. I need a global way

Comment: @ChristmasUnicorn: You should post your version of Adobe Reader if you must stick with using that reader. It will affect the proper answer(s). As an alternative, I have posted a different reader you can use and how to access it.

Comment: I already updated and I don't need to stick to that reader. I can always upgrade. +1 anyways

Comment: Strange, this video says it works for versions 6 - 10. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_N7PgpkH8lM

Comment: Really, Looks like my adobe is broken, I have been noticing some strange behaviour lately. I'll just download another one

Comment: Not a bad idea ;) Give SumatraPDF a try. Another good one is Foxit Reader, though I switched from that one a while back because of extra 3rd party stuff it wanted to install. That may have changed now, but I haven't looked back from SumatraPDF.

Comment: Thanks!!!. I just did that with the Sumtra, its a very nice editor/

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second part of your question: it is possible but not trivial to change the font and the background colour of a PDF file.

I have successfully done such edits on existing PDF files using [pdfedit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDFedit).